# How to control mouse cursor with color tracking using Aforge.net?

Tags: c#, aforge, mouse-cursor

I want to move the mouse cursor according to the color of the object. I could object tracking but I could not control the Mouse. How can I do this?

```
this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);

int xX = cu.posX(kaynakBox.Width, objectRect.X, objectRect.Width);
int yY = cu.posY(kaynakBox.Height, objectRect.Y, objectRect.Height);
```